# Given a source file, is there a way to ask gcc to return list of only directly included header files?

Tags: c++, gcc, header, include

I have tried `g++ -MM -MG -H -std=c++11 SomeSourceFile.cpp`. There are two outputs here, one from `-MM -MG` and the other from `-H`.

- `-MM -MG`: I get all non-system (user) includes, but I don't get the hierarchy of includes. I am only interested in direct includes, but this option gives me all includes.
- `-H`: I get hierarchical information of includes, but only the the ones in the compiler directory. I don't see non-system includes in the output.

Is there a way to get the direct non-system includes (even if they don't yet exist) from a source file?

Comment: If you only want direct includes, why not grep for `#include`?

Comment: Because it may be commented out?

Comment: `grep -E '^\s*#include'` then.

Comment: That could falsely capture an include with a comment block where the comment start in a former line with /* and ended in a latter line.

Answer (score 0):

Some Perl to the rescue?

```
$ cat tmp.c
#include "a.h"
$ cat a.h
#include "b.h"
$ g++ tmp.c -E | perl -ne 'if (!defined $x) {
>   if (/^# 1 "([^"]+)" 1\b/) {
>      $x = $1;
>      print "$x\n";
>   }
> } else {
>   $x = undef if /^# 1 "$x" 2\b/;
> }'
a.h
```